# Beatifulsoup not returning full html of the page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I want to scrape few pages from amazon website like title,url,aisn and i run into a problem that script only parsing 15 products while on the page it is showing 50. i decided to print out all html to console and i saw that the html is ending at 15 products without any errors from the script.
Here is the part of my script

```
keyword = "men jeans".replace(' ', '+')

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1b3) Gecko/20090305 Firefox/3.1b3 GTB5'}
url = "https://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords={}".format(keyword)

request = requests.session()
req = request.get(url, headers = headers)
sleep(3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: If I go to that page, I see `1-16 of over 50,000 results for "men+jeans"`, so I'm not sure why you are seeing 50. Try looking at the page with cookies cleared, tho.

Comment: 50 is only for one page that is being extracted, i'm using session and at the end of the script using    request.cookies.clear()

Comment: Can you post the part of the script that runs into the problem?

Comment: i already posted, exactly variable soup doesn't have full content of the HTML page

Comment: Oh, what do you mean "50 is only for one page that is being extracted"? There's only one url in the script posted, and on that page I see 16 items.

Comment: if you inspect HTML of the page each product is stored into a li element with id=result + item number for jeans there are 43 items (products)on the page for some other products it is usually around 50 products per page.

Comment: In the HTML, I see 19 <li> tags with id="result_itemnumber", and then after that, more counting up to "result_29" in a commented section which starts at <div id="results-atf-next" style="display: none;">. I guess past that, I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because few of the items are generated dynamically. There might be any better solution other than using selenium. However, as a workaround you can try the below way instead.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fetch_item(driver,keyword):
    driver.get(url.format(keyword.replace(" ", "+")))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for items in soup.select("[id^='result_']"):
        try:
            name = items.select_one("h2").text
        except AttributeError: name = ""
        print(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords={}"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        fetch_item(driver,"men jeans")
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Upon running the above script you should get 56 names or something as result.

Comment: i was thinking about that maybe product are being loaded via AJAX, but i disabled javascript in browser to check manually if it wills how less product amount and it actually showed only about 5 less so in total 50 products instead of 55

Comment: It's because `Amazon` has already detected you as a bot and they do this in some different manners. Take a breather and run again then you should get the desired results. Thanks.

Comment: and your script sometimes displays 20 products so there is only one product in a row i guess this is normal behaviour. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(1, 21):
    keyword = "red car".replace(' ', '+')
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1b3) Gecko/20090305 Firefox/3.1b3 GTB5'}
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=" + keyword + "?page=" + str(page)
    request = requests.session()
    req = request.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.findAll("li", {"class": "s-result-item"})

    for i in results:
        try:
            print(i.find("h2", {"class": "s-access-title"}).text.replace('[SPONSORED]', ''))

            print(i.find("span", {"class": "sx-price-large"}).text.replace("\n", ' '))

            print('*' * 20)
        except:
            pass
```

Amazon's page range is max till 20 here is it crawling the pages

Comment: I tried your code and it returned me 20 products from the single page but actually, there is more product available

Comment: To me i'ts showing 20 products on the page. Do you want it to crawl the pages too?

Comment: strange but when i checking manually from browsers it displaying 50 products